# Use str_replace or other function to replace tags

Tags: php

Is there a way to replace tags only if there are both open and close for example:

```
//search to replace
$text = '[b]this will be bold[/b] but this will be not.';
$search = array('[b]long string[/b]');
//replace with
$replace = array('<b>long string</b>');
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

wanted Result:

> **this will be bold** but this will be not.

I'm not sure how to set it up correctly any help will be thankful.

Comment: You need to replace a *pattern* rather than a specific string. Regular expressions allow you to do that.

Comment: Why don't you just allow for (**some**) HTML tags? Or think about markdown (there's plenty of libraries for it)

Comment: +1 for Markdown. Michel Fortin has a pretty good Markdown parser here: http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement a system of BBCodes, which you'll need to use regular expressions to do.

There's a very good article at http://thesinkfiles.hubpages.com/hub/Regex-for-BBCode-in-PHP which explains how to do this with explanations of what the various regex parts mean so that you can write your own additions later on.

The code to convert your example above on its own however is as follows:

```
$text = '[b]this will be bold[/b] but this will be not.';
$ret = $text; // So we don't overwrite the original variable.
$ret = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]#iUs', '<b>$1</b>', $ret);
```

Comment: This works Perfectly to implement my own regex on a array, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do it:

```
//search to replace
$text = '[b]this will be bold[/b] but this will be not.';
$search = array('~\[([^]]+)\]([^][]*)\[/\1\]~');
//replace with
$replace = array('<$1>$2</$1>');
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Output:

```
<b>this will be bold</b> but this will be not.
```

There's a [**PHP demo here**](http://ideone.com/B5OEvS).

Regex demo and explanation:

```
\[([^]]+)\]([^][]*)\[/\1\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jlc5NLw7c6SBbxWJ)

**Caveat emptor:** this is **very simplified** and ignores some serious safety issues. In reality, you *must* account for things like disallowing `<script>`, `<iframe>`, and other tags that could lead to cross-site scripting injections.

As always with this kind of thing, a parser is likely to beat regex.

**If you really want to use regex:** replace `([^]]+)` with a whitelisted group of tags. Example:

```
\[(b|em|i|strong)\]([^][]*)\[/\1\]  // allows only b, em, i, and strong
```

Comment: This is likely to be quite unsafe, though, subjected to XSS

Comment: Agreed, you'll be implementing more exceptions than rules. :/

Comment: @Qualcuno Yes, I agree; that's why I have a note about that at the bottom.

Comment: @TwoWholeWorms No argument.

Comment: This works very well thank you, to limit the tags to only the once i want will need to create a Regex to each tag i want? for example if i want to allow italic and bold only, and as I need more tag..

Comment: @user2444411 No, you can use just one and limit it using the kind of syntax I have at the bottom of my answer. For example, `\[(b|em|i|strong)\]([^][]*)\[/\1\]` allows bold and italics only.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you mean, answer my question but i wanted something freely to make replace [this] [/this] with something that wouldn't be call same as the tag necessarily

Comment: Ah. In that case, you might need to use an array of replacements. If you want to replace `[b]...[/b]` with `<foo>...</foo>` and `[i]...[/i]` with `<bar>...</bar>`, for example, that will require some sort of array and/or callback function.

Comment: Huh… could've sworn you had that one! :s

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to do this:

```
$text = '[b]this will be bold[/b] but this will be not.';
$text = preg_replace('/\[([a-z]+)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/', '<\1>\2</\1>', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've write for you advanced BBcode parse function

you can add any BBcode inside `$tags = 'b|url';`

for example

```
$tags = 'b|url|i|e|img';
```

also its support bbcode with inner tags for example `[url=http://www.website.com]blaa[/url]`

this is the full code

```
function parseBBCODE($text)
{
    //bbcodes tags
    $tags = 'b|url';


    //loop tags sub tags too
    while (preg_match_all('#\[('.$tags.')=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]#is',$text, $matches))
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match)
    {
       //extract tag info
       list($tag, $param, $innertext) = array($matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key]);

        //match tags and replace them
        switch ($tag)
        {
          //Bold
          case 'b':
             $replacement    = '<b>'.$innertext.'</b>';
          break;
          //link url
          case 'url':
            $replacement = '<a target="_blank" href="'.($param ? $param : $innertext).'">'.$matches[3][$key].'</a>';
          break;
          default :
           $replacement = "";
        }

      $text = str_replace($match, $replacement,$text);
      unset($match,$replacement,$param);
    }

   return $text;
}


 $search = '[b]long string [/b]  [url]http://www.google.com[/url]   [url=http://www.google.com]url with tag[/url]';

 echo parseBBCODE($search);
```